Why elements from fetch + redux don't display all the time
I'm trying to display "tweets" using a local fetch and it almost works. It randomly doesn't display some message when posted. Then when posting a new one it posts two at the same time (with the last one which didn't show previously):
Here is the component Home.js where are the fetch:
function Home() {


    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [message, setMessage] = useState("")
    const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([])
    const [charactersStyle, setCharactersStyle] = useState({})
    const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.value)
    const [posted, setPosted] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        setCharacters(message.length)
    }, [message])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (message.length > 280) {
            setCharactersStyle({ "color": "red" })
        }
        else { setCharactersStyle({}) }
    }, [message])

    const handleTweet = () => {
        if (message.length > 0 && message.length <= 280) {

            const regex = /\B\#[a-zA-Z]+\b(?!;)/

            fetch("http://localhost:3000/tweets/new", {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({ username: user.username, message }),
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    setMessage("")
                    setPosted(!posted)
                    dispatch(add(message.match(regex)))
                })
        }
    }
    const fetchTweets = async () => {

        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/tweets/all")
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data.tweets)
        dispatch(post(data.tweets))
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {

        fetchTweets();

    }, [posted])

    

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <h1>Home</h1>
            <div className={styles.inputcontainer}>
                <textarea className={styles.input} onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)} value={message} ></textarea>
                <div className={styles.charbtn}>
                    <p className={styles.characters} style={charactersStyle}>{`${characters}/280`}</p>
                    <button type="button" className={styles.tweetbtn} onClick={() => { handleTweet() }}>Tweet</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <LastTweets posted={posted} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;

And the component LastTweets.js where are displayed the tweets:
function LastTweets() {

    const tweetsToDisplay = useSelector((state) => state.tweets.value)

    console.log(tweetsToDisplay)

    let tweets;
    if (tweetsToDisplay.length > 0) {
        tweets = tweetsToDisplay.map((data, i) => {
            return <Tweet key={i} {...data} />
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {tweets}
        </div>
    )
}

export default LastTweets;

I first tried to use the get fetch in the LastTweet component but it didn't work either.
After removing the posted property from Home component like toadv1ne said and editing the fetchTweets function like so, it seems to be working:
const fetchTweets = async () => {

        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/tweets/all")
        const data = await response.json()
        dispatch(post(data.tweets))
        setPosted(false)
    }


I wonder if you need to reset posted after you've fetched the tweets. Also, it looks like you're not using posted in your LatestTweets component.

Ah yes i forgot to remove the posted property from Home. Done.

If you are going to micro-manage the posted state then you may want to also add a condition on calling fetchTweets in the useEffect hook call so it's only called when posted is true, e.g. if (posted) fetchTweets();. Don't forget to include any abort controllers to cancel any in-flight fetch requests as necessary (i.e. component unmount, another post is created, etc).

When i add the if condition it starts not working again. I think it's confusing but the posted state is only here to activate the useEffect.
